# Google Android account without Gmail

Tags: 2.2-froyo

Recently my grandmother got my uncle's old cellphone, and today I've been trying to set it up for her. It's an LG-P990, running on Android 2.2.2, which can't be further upgraded. In order to have everything run smoothly, but trying to not overcomplicate things, I set up a Google account for her, without Gmail, using her provider based email address. That worked out just fine, and I have been able to get her entire addressbook mishmash into her new Google Contacts.

However, I am not able to get the cellphone to log in to Google, as it simply responds that her account is not a Gmail account. As such, it's unable to sync her contacts etc. I'm guessing that it's due to the device running on an older version of Android, dating from prior to when Non-Gmail Google accounts were an option.

Does anyone know a way to get around this and make the device connect to her Google account, or am I forced to set up a bogus Gmail address for her as well? If so, is there a way to attach the bogus Gmail address to be made to her current Google account, and keep her provider based email address (the one she actually uses) as the main address?

Any help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a gmail account and associate the phone with that, you can simply forward the gmail email to her main email address.

I'm not sure about using the current Google account.